# Does is_child() exist in wp 3.5.1?

Tags: menus, pages, navigation

I'm trying to figure out how to get to a is_child() equivalent; I'd like to be able to target the parent page and it's children. How can this be achieved?

My pseudo-code is...

```
if (is_page('pagename') || is_child('pagename')) {...}
```

...however, the is_child() doesn't seem to work. I would like it to return true.

Comment: What exactly should it do? Return `TRUE` if the current page or the page with that slug is a child page?

Comment: Return true, sorry. I'd like to use it to filter the menu based on the page... for example currently I can...

    if (is_page('home')) { wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container_class' => 'mainMenu' ) ); }

...which works, but I can't figure out an is_page('home) || is_child('home') type of setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for a specific parent ID use `$post->post_parent=="123"` and replace "123" with the parent ID of your choice.

I learned how to do this by using the Widget Logic plugin. From the [Widget Logic notes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/):

`global $post; return (is_page('pagename') || ($post->post_parent=="13"));` -- home page OR the page that's a child of page 13

Edit: A better source is [Testing for sub-Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_sub-Pages) in the codex.

Comment: I could be using it wrong, but does this also work for pages, not posts? I'm trying to reduce code as much as possible by condensing it into one conditional... if (is_page('pagename') || ($post->post_parent=='pagename')) didn't return errors, but also did not work on the child pages

Comment: It may require that you use the actual parent ID instead of the pagename. Have you tried that? Also try removing the parenthesis around `($post->post_parent=='pagename')` as they don't appear to be necessary here. See [snippet 3](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_sub-Pages) in the codex which uses this syntax `if ( is_page( 'about' ) || '2' == $post->post_parent )`

Comment: @beta208 Posts don't have parents, so it doesn't make sense for to work with posts...

Comment: Also tried if (is_page('pagename') || 'pagename' == $post->post_parent) {...} 

Which didn't work; I'd love to use the ID, but I'm not seeing it. When I click Quickedit see the title, the slug, date, author, password, parent, order, and template.

Comment: The snippet 3 looks like my solution, it may just be that I'm needing to find the equivalent of the ID for my pages

Comment: You can get the ID for the parent page by going to the page editor for that page. It will be in the url. It will look something like `https://dreamloan.pro/wp-admin/post.php?post=3165&action=edit` where 3165 is the ID.

Comment: Thank you. I did find the ID as stated above and the provided snippet 3 was my solution! Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

This will check for descendancy rather than strict parent-child relationship:

```
/**
 * Is the current page a descendent of page identified by the path (not slug).
 * A page is not a descendent of itself!
 * @param string $page_path The path of the page, e.g. mypage/mysubpage 
 * @return boolean True if current page is a descednent of specified $page_path. False otherwise.
 */
function is_descendent_of( $page_path ){

    if( !is_page() ){
        return false;
    }

    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( get_queried_object_id() );
    $page = get_page_by_path( $page_path );
    if( $page )
        return in_array( $page->ID, $ancestors );
    return false;   
}
```

And for strict parent-child checking:

```
/**
 * Is the current page a child of the page identified by the path (not slug).
 * A page is not a child of itself! Child != descendant.
 * @param string $page_path The path of the page, e.g. mypage/mysubpage
 * @return boolean True if current page is a child of specified $page_path. False otherwise.
 */
function is_child_of( $page_path ){

    if( !is_page() ){
        return false;
    }

    $page = get_page_by_path( $page_path );
    $current_page = get_post();

    if( $page )
        return $current_page->post_parent == $page->ID;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching for this function to use with Widget Logic, I found [this snippet](http://bavotasan.com/2011/is_child-conditional-function-for-wordpress/), adapted bellow:

```
/**
 * Check if a page is child of another 
 * 
 * @param mixed $page_id_or_slug Provide the parent ID or Slug
 * @return bool Whether the page is child or not of the given parent
 */
function is_child( $page_id_or_slug ) 
{ 
    global $post; 
    if( !is_page() )
        return false;

    # Slug provided, get ID
    if( !is_int( $page_id_or_slug ) ) 
    {
        $page = get_page_by_path( $page_id_or_slug );
        $page_id_or_slug = $page->ID;
    } 

    return $post->post_parent == $page_id_or_slug; 
}
```